# How can I write a function which gives the output in the below format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

Write a function which, given the following input, generates the given output

Input: ["John", false, "Doe", 46, 6.5, 7, true];

Output: [["John", "Doe"], [46, 7], [6.5], [false, true]];

```js
function reFactor() {
        var input = ["John", false, "Doe", 46, 6.5, 7, true];
        
        for (var i=0; i <input.length; i++) {
          if (typeof input[i] === "string") {
            alert("String");
          }
          else if (typeof input[i] === "number") {
            alert("Number");
          }
          else if (typeof input[i] === "boolean") {
            alert("Boolean");
          }
        }
      }
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="reFactor()" value="Click">
```

I am able to  reach till this step. How do I use map function here?

Comment: [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) isn't appropriate here as you are looking to return an array of a different length than the original. If you wanted to use an array method you would want to look at [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of, would be have separate arrays for each type that you need:

```js
function reFactor() {
  var input = ["John", false, "Doe", 46, 6.5, 7, true];
  var stringInput = [];
  var numberInput = [];
  var booleanInput = [];
  
  for (var i=0; i <input.length; i++) {
    if (typeof input[i] === "string") {
      stringInput.push(input[i])
    }
    else if (typeof input[i] === "number") {
      numberInput.push(input[i])
    }
    else if (typeof input[i] === "boolean") {
      booleanInput.push(input[i])
    }
  }

  var result = [stringInput, numberInput, booleanInput]
  console.log(result)
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="reFactor()" value="Click">
```

### Extra note:

To differentiate between the "float" and "integer" numbers, you would need to use some hack. See: [How to differentiate between a one-decimal float and integer in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32210400/how-to-differentiate-between-a-one-decimal-float-and-integer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Bruno's answer is what you are asking for I think. But just for fun, a more general way to break down your values by type:

Javascript:

```
function reFactor(input) {
    const result = {}
    input.map((val) => {
        const key = typeof val;
        if (key in result) {
            result[key].push(val);
        } else {
            result[key] = [val]
        }
    }, {})
    
    return result;
  }

  const x = ["John", false, "Doe", 46, 6.5, 7, true];

  const rX = reFactor(x);
  console.log(rX)
```

Typescript:

```
const VarType = ["string" , "number" , "bigint" , "boolean" , "symbol" , "undefined" , "object" , "function"] as const

type ResultSetValue = {
    [key: string]: any[]
}

function reFactor(input: any[]) {
    const result: ResultSetValue = {}
    input.map((val) => {
        const key = typeof val;
        if (key in result) {
            result[key].push(val);
        } else {
            result[key] = [val]
        }
    }, {} as ResultSetValue)
    
    return result;
  }

  const x = ["John", false, "Doe", 46, 6.5, 7, true];

  const rX = reFactor(x);
  console.log(rX)
```

This returns:

```
{ 
  string: [ 'John', 'Doe' ], 
  boolean: [ false, true ], 
  number: [ 46, 6.5, 7 ] 
}
```

Comment: Nice alternative! I would just suggest removing the types to be less confuse. Seems like author is using basic Javascript, not Typescript :)